# Максимальная бинарная куча. Алгоритмическая задача

Tags: алгоритм

Дано:

Начальный стек: [9,7,8,6,4,5,6,1,5]

Мы берем данные из стека и получается куча такого вида:

[image: куча]

Что нужно узнать

1. количество способов, которыми мы можем вернуть данные обратно в стек, так чтобы при следующем извлечении у нас снова получалась бинарная куча отличная от начальной? Например первый способ, начиная с конца берем последовательно каждый элемент и отправляем его в стек.
2. сколько бинарных максимальных куч можно построить из значений данного стека?
3. как изменится количество куч во втором пункте, если мы прибавим/удалим элемент(ы), т.е. общее решение.

Буду благодарен любым комментариям, которые помогут ответить на поставленные вопросы.

Comment: Что такое "начиная с конца" для кучи?

Comment: с последнего индекса до нулевого. операция обратная той, через которую мы получили дерево

Comment: Не понял. Куча - это дерево, как вы сами сказали. Что такое "индекс" в дереве?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на первый пункт

arrangement_number = 0
desired_heap = [9, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5]

for permutation in itertools.permutations(desired_heap):
    binary_heap = BinHeap()
    for item in permutation:
        binary_heap.insert(item)
    if binary_heap._hl == desired_heap:
        arrangement_number += 1

print("Total: ", arrangement_number)